# Swift: Detect video end

Tags: ios, swift, video, avplayer

I have to play some videos in my swift application. The video is working perfectly but I want to detect when the video is ended. I searched about that then I found that the `NotificationCenter` is the solution for that. I used this code but my application crash at the end of the video.

This is my code:

```
func playVideo(url: NSURL){
let player = AVPlayer(url: url as URL)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: Selector(("playerDidFinishPlaying")), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: player.currentItem)
player.play()
}

func playerDidFinishPlaying(note: NSNotification) {
        print("Video Finished")
    }
```

The error is:

```
[myApp.myViewController playerDidFinishPlaying]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x79669740
```

Any help please?

Comment: Can you give me more details please?

Comment: Code like `url:NSURL` and `func playerDidFinishPlaying(note:` is Swift 2. You need to write your code in Swift 3. Right now you have a kind of mixture of Swift 2 and Swift 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your selector is wrong, obviously. You are saying:

```
Selector(("playerDidFinishPlaying"))
```

But that is not the Objective-C name of your method.

Clearly, you don't know how to make the Objective-C name of your method. And you don't have to! This is exactly what `#selector` syntax solves. Just use it:

```
#selector(playerDidFinishPlaying)
```

And now it will work, because Swift will solve the problem you don't know how to solve.

Comment: I've answered the question you actually asked, and I believe I answered it correctly. My job here is done.

Comment: Thank you it works. I believe that I have to pay more attention to the swift version and syntax. Thanks again, you're the best!

Comment: If you want to understand what `#selector` syntax is doing for you, read my book: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch02.html#_selectors

Comment: Your blog is so interesting! Thank you so much!!